# Gerrit rebase local branch with upstream master

Tags: git, gerrit

I need some help with pushing the community rebased branch to our gerrit.

We have a project which is forked out from a community project. Earlier we didn't use gerrit so rebase and push was easy. But with gerrit now in picture, things are confusing for me.

I need to rebase our forked out release branch with upstream release branch.

Here is what I did till now

```
git checkout -b local_zoomba1 remotes/origin/zoomba1
git remote add upstream <upstream git repo>
git fetch upstream
git rebase remotes/upstream/stable/zoomba1
```

After this, there were some conflicts which I resolved. Then added an empty commit to mark rebase

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "Rebased with community zoomba1 release"
```

Now the fun began :)

When I did git review, it gave error that commiter mail id doesn't match my id. So I gave myself permission to 'Forge Committer' and 'Forge Author'

Now it shows all the commits but finally complains:

```
You are about to submit multiple commits. This is expected if you are
submitting a commit that is dependent on one or more in-review
commits. Otherwise you should consider squashing your changes
into one commit before submitting.

The outstanding commits are:
...
...
Type 'yes' to confirm, other to cancel: yes
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
remote: ERROR: missing Change-Id in commit message footer
remote:
remote: Hint: To automatically insert Change-Id, install the hook:
...
remote: And then amend the commit:
remote:   git commit --amend
remote:
```

- Ofcourse there are many commits without change-id's (the ones which are 'merge' commits). I can't go back and assign some random change-id's to them. How should I proceed here ?
- Also, I need to understand how gerrit reacts when it encounters unknown change-id's which are coming from community ?
- Will this all go under one big commit or is this not the way to go ?
- Can I bypass gerrit and directly push these to git ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, of course, squash all community commits in just one big commit and put the Change-Id on it but this is not the best thing to do. I think that, in this case, you don't want to review all community commits, right? This task doen't make sense. So, the best approach is to push straight to branch bypassing Gerrit. How to do this?

1) You need to have ALLOW permission in "Push" and "Push Merge Commit" categories of the "refs/heads/*" reference

2) You need to push to "refs/heads/BRANCH" instead of "refs/for/BRANCH"

Comment: Yes, I don't want to squash them neither review them. I can try the ALLOW permission you have mentioned. But didn't understand the /heads/ /for/ branch thing. Also what would the push command look like ?

Comment: Ok, I have both the permission on "refs/heads/*" now. But still not sure what you meant by "refs/heads/BRANCH" instead of "refs/for/BRANCH". Will this not work `git push origin local_zoomba1:zoomba1`

Comment: Tried a --dry-run with this. It fails :( `# git push --dry-run origin local_zoomba1:zoomba1
 ! [rejected]        local_zoomba1 -> zoomba1 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to ...
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and merge the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: To push to review, you have to execute: git push origin local_zoomba1:refs/for/zoomba1. To push straight to the branch (bypassing the review), you have to execute: git push origin local_zoomba1:refs/heads/zoomba1. When you executed "git push origin local_zoomba1:zoomba1" the effect was the same of using the "refs/heads" prefix. The "non-fast-forward" you have received probably is because you need to rebase your commit again (someone have submitted a new commit to the tip of the branch you have based).

Comment: For more details on the refs/for "magical" branch see the Gerrit documentation in https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-quick.html#_creating_the_review

Comment: Thanks for the link. About the non-fast-forward error, there is nothing new on the branch. But the commits which are on the forked branch have not been submitted to community. Maybe those are causing issue ? I noticed some empty 'merge' commits on the forked branch have gone missing after rebase. Also the commits on the forked branch have not been submitted to community, would they be causing issue ?

Comment: If I rethink about this case, maybe 'rebase' will not work. I'll need to 'merge' instead ? Checkout remote branch, merge my local branch, resolve conflict and commit. Then push ?

Comment: Yes. I would do a little bit different: checkout local branch, merge remote branch, resolve conflicts and push. In time: don't do any extra "empty" commit... if you want to "mark" something always use a tag.

Comment: I am still wondering why rebase and push didn't work. The 'merge' commits generated by Gerrit vanished after rebase with upstream. Would that be causing PUSH issue ? How to work around that ?

Comment: Maybe I need `rebase --preserve-merges`, then it will preserve the empty merge commits and won't give the error of non-fast-forward?

Comment: Yes. I agree with you.